# Proof that the variable from ajax call exists

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I have created a button "clear all",
 which sends data to 'data.php' at the click of the button via ajax

```
</head>
 <body> 
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function klick(id){
           $.ajax({
           type:"POST",
           url:"data.php",
           data:{id:id},                        
           success:function(resp){
           $('#w3').html(resp);                       
          }
        });                   
       } 
  </script>        
<a href="shop.php">shop</a>
<br><br>

   <button type='button'onclick= " klick()"/>clear all</button> 

</body>
</html>
```

and this is my data.php page,
so what i want to do is overwriting $ _SESSION ['warenkorb'] with an empty array If the variable from the call is present in the "data.php" page.

Something like this: `$_SESSION['warenkorb']=array();`

```
 <html>
 <head>
   <title>DATA</title>
    <script src="https://www.novastorm.de/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>    

  <?php         
     include 'produkte.php';           
     if(!isset($_SESSION['warenkorb'])){  
       $_SESSION['warenkorb']=array();
         }                                
     if(isset($_POST['id'])){             
      foreach($a as $key =>$value){  
      if($value['id']==$_POST['id']){                   
       $_SESSION['warenkorb'][]= $_POST['id'];              
       }              
     }
    }     
      print_r(count($_SESSION['warenkorb']));       
   ?>      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Session data is available only after page reload. If you are loading data dynamically without page reload, use other options.

Comment: from where `$a` comes? and you have to use `session_start();` in your php page on top

Comment: yes i would like to load data dynamically without page reload but i don't know the other options that i can use @ Dainis Abols

Comment: $a from an another array page that i use but i think it's not important @Alive to Die